# suggestions for first-time importing and checking out project

Tags: svn, version-control

Subversion 1.6.6 using the commend line client

Importing and checking out project for the first-time.

I find that when I create a new project I do the normal directory structure, i.e.

```
game_sys_proj
    /trunk
    /branches
    /tags
```

Steps :

```
1) I import game_sys_proj to subversion repository. 
2) Delete game_sys_proj directory. 
3) Checkout game_sys_proj project.
```

This will create the exact duplicate of what I deleted.

I am just wondering is there another way of doing this? What do other developers do when they import and checkout for the first time?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of importing and deleting, you can use an in-place checkout.  For example, if you created your repository at `file:///var/svn/game_sys_proj`, just checkout the trunk of the new repository to your current directory:

```
$ cd game_sys_proj
$ svn co file:///var/svn/game_sys_proj/trunk .
$ svn add foo bar baz # add all files/directories you want in version control
$ svn commit
```

Also see [the FAQ](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#in-place-import).